# Javascript passing variable in function

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript. I am creating a text adventure. I am trying to write a function to take a given parameter, and use the .toLowerCase and return it as the same variable. I think I have the general idea to do it, but I just can not get it to work. Thanks!

```
function lowercase(a){
    return a.toLowerCase();
}

var alive = 1;
while(alive == 1){
    var name = prompt("What is your name?");
    lowercase(name);
    document.write("Hello " + name + "!\n");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Strings are **immutable**. Every method that changes a string value in any way returns a *new* string.

Comment: Why are you running a `while` loop and then breaking out of it straight away?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I was just doing that for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `name = lowercase(name);`
the function returns a result, but you have to assign this result to a variable in order to use it after, or you can simply say

```
document.write('Hello' + lowercase(name) + 'something');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result of the function:

```
name = lowercase(name);
```

Are you new to programming in general? Because Javascript is similar to most other language in this regard.

Comment: Also, you can skip `lowercase(a)` completely and just do this: `name = name.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: @Dai Of course, but it seems like he's trying to learn how to write and use functions.

Comment: Yes @Dia. I do realize how to use .toLowerCase, but I want to learn how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = lowercase(name);
```

Since you are returning the value in your function, you must reinitialize the value of the variable. Javascript as far as I know is not a "pass by reference" language. It has always been a "pass by value". Read more about it here.

[What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

The value of the name variable isn't being changed at the moment, you need to assign it to the result of the function.

```js
function lowercase(a){
    return a.toLowerCase();
}

var alive = 1;
while(alive == 1){
    var name = prompt("What is your name?");
    name = lowercase(name);
    document.write("Hello " + name + "!\n");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = lowercase(name);
```

Note, you should almost always use "===" instead of "==". "===" tests whether something's value and data type (number, string, boolean, object, etc.) matches another, whereas "==" only tests whether the values match (after performing a type conversion). For example:

```
if ("42" == 42) { // true (string 42 equals number 42)
if ("42" === 42) { // false (string does not equal number, what you want)
```